# Drawing lines on Content pane Javax swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to separate pieces of my JFrame window with lines like this:

[image]

How can I do this? I've searched but it's hard to search as I'm not really too sure how to describe it without the image.

Comment: use jseparator https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSeparator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want, it is called separator and the class which can be used in Swing is [JSeparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html)

[image]

Comment: Glad, that it helped... :)